# Unable to fetch data from all pages in scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am unable to fetch all pages using below code it only gives data upto page 90 and then show arribute error.
I am using next button url to move to the next page. But after page 90 it is giving error that i have mentioned below.

Running this code:

```
import scrapy
import re

class PaginationSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pagination'
    allowed_domains = ['www.farfetch.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.farfetch.com/de/shopping/men/shoes-2/items.aspx?page=1']

    total_pages_pattern = r'"totalPages":(\d+)'
    current_page_pattern = r"page=(\d+)"

    def parse(self, response):
        
        number_of_pages= int(re.search(self.total_pages_pattern, str(response.body)).group(1))
        current_page = int(re.search(self.current_page_pattern, response.url).group(1))
        
        for brand in response.xpath("//h3[@itemprop='brand']//text()"):

            yield {
                "brand":brand.get()
            }

        if current_page <= number_of_pages:

            next_page = "https://www.farfetch.com/de/shopping/men/shoes-2/items.aspx?page=" + str(current_page+1)
            
            print("Current_page:" + str(current_page))

            yield response.follow(url=next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Error :
[image: Error image]

Comment: Class is working fine and the error occurred in the `website1.py` line 48. I guess you didn't post the full code.

Comment: I have posted full code line 48 is this  `current_page = int(re.search(self.current_page_pattern, response.url).group(1))`  one you can see in Error image

Answer (score 1):

```
    current_page = int(re.search(self.current_page_pattern, response.url).group(1))
```

`re.search()` method will return a Re object if the pattern matches the string. If there is no match, it will return `None`. So, when the pattern doesn't match, you are calling `.group(1)` in `None`.

That's why you are getting an `AttributeError`.

I didn't execute you code, but you can probably solve it by adding a if statement.